# How does the locky malware work?

Tags: administrator, malware

I've been hearing a lot about the locky malware recently. I've heard that it can be deployed through Word macros.

**I'd like to know how the malware can do it's thing without needing administrator privileges.**

Comment: Answered the bold part; as for the deployment, receiving a lot of these variant daily I can see that a lot of variants run a vbscript or cscript (some standalone, some in macro) that download and run the actual virus

Comment: @TomWijsman - Thank you for the quick and thorough explanation!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Access to your personal files only requires personal privileges, **not** administrator privileges.

The moment you open the virus, it already runs with personal privileges, it does not need any more consent than you clicking on it. From there on, it just enumerates whichever files it can find and is only able to encrypt those which you have the privilege to change them.

In other words, it can do as much as you could do yourself using a text editor without an UAC prompt.

For the sake of completeness; please note that personal privileges include guest and some group privileges, which means public folders, USB thumb drives and open or mounted network shares are often affected too. There may be variants that use [escalation exploits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Privilege_escalation) to be able to encrypt more.